# linq date format won't go into list

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

Trying to set Shortdate list into a Datagrid.ItemsSource

```
var query = from loan in Loans  
            select new {Date = loan.StatusCommittedDate}  
DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList(); `
```

it displays Date in "3/25/2011 12:00:00 AM" Format in the DataGrid
I only need the date, not the time so my Current Linq is

```
var query = from loan in Loans  
            select new {Date = loan.StatusCommittedDate.ToString()}  
DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList()`
```

which displays  in "`2011-03-25`" format which is what I want. So the Linq query works, but inputting it into the datagrid is wrong and if I can get some guidances please.
When I try to display the information through a Datagrid in WPF I get this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '`System.String
>   ToString()`' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Comment: There are several ways to format a datagrid column for dates instead of manipulating your data directly.

Comment: Hello, How abouts may I do this? I tried Datagrid.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format but didn't quite work, I'm using telerik Datagrid and they don't contain a definition for DefaultCellStyle.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the error message is fairly self explanatory.  The query provider doesn't know how to translate `ToString`, so you need to ensure that the query you ask it to translate doesn't include it.  You can use `AsEnumerable` as a way of indicating that the all subsequent operations should be performed on the application side, not translated into the query:

```
var query = Loans.Select(loan => loan.StatusCommittedDate)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(date => new{ Date = date.ToShortDateString() });
```

Comment: I just tried this code, thank you for the input it's much appreciated! The date syntax hasn't changed to the appropriate one I was looking for.

Comment: @user2785177 That's because the default `ToString` value of a `DateTime` prints both the date and the time.  The point is that that is the appropriate place to format the date as a string, however you want to do it.

Comment: Alright sounds good, do you possibly think you can write that in similiar linq syntax as how I wrote it. It's just easier for me to understand. It's to be applied to the bigger picture, I just simplified for obvious reasons.

Comment: @user2785177 You *can*, but it'll be quite a lot messier as there's no query syntax equivalent of `AsEnumerable`.  You're free to substitute either or both of the `Select`s as query syntax operations.